# a pair-case multiplication of variables/df (R)

Tags: r, dataframe, vector

I've a question about a pair-case multiplication of variables/df in R.

Consider the following problem:
having data in vector (or in dataframe) that have labels and values as follow:

```
alpha_lab <- c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")
alpha_num <- c(15.28767,  44.38356,  73.47945, 103.56164, 133.64384, 163.72603, 193.80822, 224.38356, 254.46575, 284.54795, 314.63014, 344.71233)
```

the *alpha_num* is a product of other calculations (irrelevant), the following values correspond to their labels in *alpha_lab* (so January = 15.28767, April = 103.56164...). 
I also have a dataframe with "case", "month" (as *int*), "year" and "value":

```
> df_values
# A tibble: 1,173 x 4
# Groups:   case, month 
   case    month  year  value
   <chr>   <int> <int>  <dbl>
 1 A1          1  2009  121. 
 2 A1          1  2010  177. 
 3 A1          1  2011  220. 
 4 A1          1  2012  196. 
 5 A1          1  2013  161. 
 6 A1          1  2014  142. 
 7 A1          2  2009   82.3
 8 A1          2  2010  169. 
 9 A1          2  2011  194. 
10 A1          2  2012  169. 
# ... with 1,163 more rows
```

what I am looking for, is a way to compute for each case (20 different) in each month-year a product of

```
value * alpha_num
```

where *alpha_num* is taken only for a calculated month, so for example:

```
row 1 (A1, January 2009 case): 121 * 15.28767
row 5 (A1, January 2013 case): 161 * 15.28767
row 7 (A1, February 2011 case): 82.3 * 44.38356
```

and so on for each case in each month in each year...

Is there a way to compute this without adding corresponding *alpha_num* value to *df_values* table one-by-one month case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This should be helpful:

```
library(dplyr)

# original vectors
alpha_lab <- c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")
alpha_num <- c(15.28767,  44.38356,  73.47945, 103.56164, 133.64384, 163.72603, 193.80822, 224.38356, 254.46575, 284.54795, 314.63014, 344.71233)

# example of your dataframe
df_values = data.frame(case = c("A1", "A1"),
                       month = c(1, 2),
                       year = c(2009, 2009),
                       value = c(121, 82.3),  stringsAsFactors = F)

df_values %>% mutate(new_col = value * alpha_num[month])

#   case month year value  new_col
# 1   A1     1 2009 121.0 1849.808
# 2   A1     2 2009  82.3 3652.767
```

Note that this works because your `alpha_lab` vector has the months in the right order. i.e. Jan, Feb, ..., Dec represent the positions 1, 2, ..., 12.

Comment: This results in: "Error in alpha_num[month] : invalid subscript type 'closure'", what am I missing?

Comment: Is that an error based on my code? Or when you try to apply it on your real dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

You can also try to work with an lookup table and `dplyr::left_join`.

```
library("magrittr")

sampleData <- tibble::tibble(

  case = "A1", 
  month = rep(1:12, each = 6), 
  year = rep(2009:2014, 12), 
  value = runif(72, 10, 130)


)



lookup_table <- tibble::tibble(

  alpha_lab = c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"),
  alpha_id = 1:12,
  alpha_num = c(15.28767,  44.38356,  73.47945, 103.56164, 133.64384, 163.72603, 193.80822, 224.38356, 254.46575, 284.54795, 314.63014, 344.71233)


)

result <- dplyr::left_join(sampleData, lookup_table, by = c("month" = "alpha_id")) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(new_col = alpha_num * value) %>%
  dplyr::select(-alpha_num, -alpha_lab)
```